# Windows Taskbar not working after switching user (2 users are logged on at once)

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I have a really odd problem with Windows 10 2004 (up to date): After switching to another user the taskbar isn't loaded correctly (it is not responding showing hour glas on hover).

What does not help:

- restarting Explorer
- logging off and on again

What does help:

- logging off the other user
- restart and logging in with desired user

I do not have any "snake oil" installed nor any 3rd party anti virus. The only part constantly changing are games installed via steam.
So it seems to be related to 2 users concurrently logged in?! It does not matter what users - only the first one gets a working taskbar. (i have 4 local user, can reproduce with any combination)

Any ideas to further investigate or solve this issue?